# ORA-01019 connecting to Oracle from Excel

Tags: oracle, excel, oracle10g, vba

I have installed Oracle 10g Express Edition. When try to test the connection I am getting the error "Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01019".

Below is my code.

```
  strConnection = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for 
  Oracle};Server=Servername;Uid=username;Pwd=password;"    
  Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  conn.Open strConnection

  conn.Close
  Set conn = Nothing
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: ORA-01019 means "unable to allocate memory in the user side".

Comment: First, reformat text of your question - move text out of [code] block, fix indentation.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the database from SQL*Plus? Does the Apex interface run without problem?

Comment: In Q, you say you are retrieving text. Do you mean retrieval from Excel ? Because regarding DB I see only insertion

Comment: Check out the comments here: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=537456

Comment: Jeffrey have a good idea. Try to comment out lines between connect / disconnect

Comment: Jeffery .. How to allocate memory in the user side

Comment: Alexander Malakhov...the insertion query is commented,the error is 
 throwed at conn.open

Comment: @ramesh: Oh, I see - I have a little exp with VBA. Have you checked out link by Jeffrey ? It seems, guy have had exactly the same problem

Comment: @ramesh: btw, if you start your comment with "@user_name" (without quotes) - that user will get notification that you wrote smth to him. And hence reply earlier

Comment: @ Alexander Malakhov : I checked the link given by Jeffrey..but nothing worked for me..Do you know How to allocate memory in the user side

Answer (score 1):

I had the following error occur recently.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): ORA-01019: unable to allocate memory in the user side
at ADODB.ConnectionClass.Open(String ConnectionString, String UserID, String Password, Int32 Options)
```

I managed to resolve the problem by simply modifying my connection string.

from:

```
 "Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=tprss;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword"
```

To:

```
   "Provider=MSDASQL;Data Source=tprss;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword"
```

someone modified/updated the components on the box.

Answer (score 0):

"ORA-01019 unable to allocate memory in the user side

Cause: The user side memory allocator returned an error.

Action: Increase the size of the process heap or switch to the old set of calls."

Followup from the comments:

Could you try this code?

```
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim CP As ADODB.Command
Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Conn As String
Dim QSQL As String

'Connect to Oracele server begin
Conn = "DRIVER={ORACLE ODBC DRIVER};SERVER=Service name;UID=username;PWD=password;DBQ=Service name;DBA=W;APA=T;FEN=T;QTO=T;FRC=10;FDL=10;LOB=T;RST=T;FRL=F;MTS=F;CSR=F;PFC=10;TLO=O;"

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection

With Cn
     .ConnectionString = Conn
     .CursorLocation = adUseClient
     .Open
End With

If Cn.State = adStateOpen Then
    MsgBox "Connection successful."
End If

'Connect to Oracle server end


'close connection begin

Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing
Set CP = Nothing
```

'close connection end

Comment: How to Increase the size of the process heap or switch to the old set of calls

Comment: I've been trying to google that for you but I can't really find a concrete answer

Comment: I hope this helps a little but I couldn't find how to do it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810466.aspx

Comment: Actually i am connecting from excel is that a problem

Comment: That's not a problem. I've tried looking for a working example for you. Maybe you should try this. (Look in the post for the code)

Comment: Thanks Sjuul Janssen..but it is throwing error as 'Datasource name not found and no default driver found' and one more thing can we connect from excel to oracle without oracle client installed in the client system

Answer (score 0):

(This didnt fit in a Comment box)

You need at least one driver. The oracle driver is best but Microsoft Driver will work too.

Lets first try to make a connection string. Right click on your desktop and the create a new .txt  file.
Now rename your textfile to something.udl 
Double click on the udl file. Go to "Provider" and select Microsoft OLEDB Provider for Oracle. Then click on next. In the server name field you fill in your TNS name. Then username and password and put a V inside "Allow saving password" (we will need this) And click on test connection. Make sure this works.

If it works then click on OK. Now open the UDL file with a text editor. You will see something similar to:

```
[oledb]
; Everything after this line is an OLE DB initstring
Provider=MSDAORA.1;Password=yourpw;User ID=youruser;Data Source=yourTNS;Persist Security Info=True
```

Copy this part into your connection string:

```
Provider=MSDAORA.1;Password=yourpw;User ID=youruser;Data Source=yourTNS
```

Now your connection string should look like:

```
Conn = "Provider=MSDAORA.1;Password=yourpw;User ID=youruser;Data Source=yourTNS"
```

I hope this works.

Comment: Thanks Sjuul Janssen i will try this and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem, specifically on Windows 7 when using the Microsoft OleDb driver from VB6.
Following the instructions in this post fixed out problem:
http://prasanth4microsoft.blogspot.com/2010/11/windows7-excel-vba-ora-01019-unable-to.html

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem also but it is on win10.. After I have tried a lots of different solution from web .. Finally.. it worked to change connection string to fix this problem.. But I changed `"Provider=MSDAORA.1"` to `"Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle"`